# How can we count number of rows in Talend jobs

Tags: if-statement, etl, talend

I have a scenario in which I only process my job only when i have numbers of rows greater then two.
I used MySqlInput and tMap and tLog components in my job.

Comment: Please take a look at the [**How do I ask a good question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and then consider improving your question.

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of your job?

Comment: Did the answer help you? If not could you provide more info?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want a `Run if` connection between 2 components somewhere (they both have to be sub job startable - they should have a green square background when you drop them on to the canvas) and to use the `NB_Line` variable from the previous sub job component with something like this as your `Run if` condition (click the link and then click the `component` tab):

```
((Integer)globalMap.get("tMysqlInput_1_NB_LINE")) > 2
```

Be aware that the `NB_Line` functionality is only usable at the end of a sub job and can have "interesting" effects when using mid job but the `Run if` will end that first sub job and conditionally start the second one. If you are unable to find a way to break your job into 2 sub jobs then you can always use a `tHash` or a `tBuffer` output followed by an input and put the `Run if` link between the two.

Comment: Thanks ydaetskcoR, that code worked for me, i know that code already. but i was using that with main flow. where that code only works with onComponentOk.

Comment: @Brij If the answer was useful to you consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?lq=1) so that others can more easily see that there is an answer to their problem. You also gain 2 reputation for it!